# Плавные переходы по якорям

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать так, чтоб переход от якоря к якорю был плавным, без использования jquery. лучше на css.

```
<a href="#totop"> to top </a>
```

Comment: Оформляйте пожалуйста правильно вопросы. В чем проблема, части кода, которые у вас получились. Мне например якорь сейчас ассоциируется с корабельным. Поправьте свой вопрос

Comment: вряд ли такое возможно.

Comment: без js не реально

Answer (score 4):

Вот интересный вариант:

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.5rem;
  z-index: 10;
  background: white;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 0 0 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li:nth-child( 3n + 1),
#main .block:nth-child( 3n + 1) {
  background: gold;
}

ul li:nth-child( 3n + 2),
#main .block:nth-child( 3n + 2) {
  background: red;
}

ul li:nth-child( 3n + 3),
#main .block:nth-child( 3n + 3) {
  background: chocolate;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1.5rem 0 0;
  padding: 0.3rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.3rem 1.5rem;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0);
  transform: translateZ( 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.block h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 200px;
  top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

a[ id="block__one"]:target~#main article.block {
  -webkit-transform: translateY( 0px);
  transform: translateY( 0px);
}

a[ id="block__two"]:target~#main article.block {
  -webkit-transform: translateY( -500px);
  transform: translateY( -500px);
}

a[ id="block_three"]:target~#main article.block {
  -webkit-transform: translateY( -1000px);
  transform: translateY( -1000px);
}
```

```html
<header class="navigation">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#block__one">Блок 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#block__two">Блок 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#block_three">Блок 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<a id="block__one"></a>
<a id="block__two"></a>
<a id="block_three"></a>
<section id="main">
  <article class="block" id="block__one">
    <h1>Блок 1</h1>
  </article>
  <article class="block" id="block__two">
    <h1>Блок 2</h1>
  </article>
  <article class="block" id="block_three">
    <h1>Блок 3</h1>
  </article>
</section>
```